# flutter: how to pass value to a dialogbox?

Tags: flutter, dart

let say I have a function to display a dialog box as following, how to make it accepts a value and show it on the dialog?  Error msg as below after code sample, I don't get what it means.  Thankyou

```
  Future _showMyDialog(String message) async {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: true, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Warning'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Text(message),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

error msg:
If the [style] argument is null, the text will use the style from the closest enclosing [DefaultTextStyle].

The [data] parameter must not be null.

The [overflow] property's behavior is affected by the [softWrap] argument. If the [softWrap] is true or null, the glyph causing overflow, and those that follow, will not be rendered. Otherwise, it will be shown with the given overflow option.

Comment: Your Code is correctly working not any error/problem or warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SteveT if you removed the `const` from children of Listbody then you issue will be removed.

```dart
 Future _showMyDialog(String message) async {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: true, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Warning'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(message),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```